# Magento 2 : Modify Name of Product Category With API Rest

Tags: magento2, product, category, rest-api

How to change **name of product category** with **API Rest**? The URL is  http://localhost:8082/magento/index.php/rest/V1/categories/26 and JSON is

```
{
   "category": {
      "id": 35,
      "parent_id": 34,
      "is_active": true,
      "position": 4,
      "name": "bio 33",
      "level": 2
   }
}
```

The name is only modified on front but not in back.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add storeId... i tried and if I use setStoreId(0) then backend is changed too.